# x86 c linux inline asm mess up registers

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I am trying to get the stack pointer and save it into a local variable in my c program.

```
int stack_pointer;
asm("movl %%esp, %0;":"=r"(stack_pointer));
```

I have other function calls and codes after this line.
however their outputs are messed up. I doubt that this line modified a register and did not change it back to its original value. how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to get assembly output for your function? `gcc -S`...

Comment: I think when GAS sees a ';' character at the end of a line (instead of '\n'), it silently switches to "mangle mode" and doesn't bother telling you that you've got a syntax error.

Comment: @Brendan `;` is not a syntax error in GAS x86. It is used to separate statements. It is perfectly fine to put one at the end of a line.

Comment: I fixed it. it's because I didn't flush my stdout